# Unpivot and Pivot does not return data

Tags: pivot, unpivot

I'm trying to return data as columns.

I've written this unpivot and pivot query:

```
`select StockItemCode, barcode, barcode2 from (select StockItemCode, col+cast(seq as varchar(20)) col, value   from  (
select 
  (select min(StockItemCode) 
   from RTLBarCode t2
   where t.StockItemCode = t2.StockItemCode) StockItemCode, 
  cast(BarCode as varchar(20)) barcode, 
     row_number() over(partition by StockItemCode order by StockItemCode) seq
from RTLBarCode t) d  unpivot(
value
for col in (barcode)  ) unpiv) src pivot (  max(value)  for col in (barcode, barcode2)) piv;`
```

But the problem is only the "Barcode2" field are returning a value (the barcode field returns a null when in fact there is a value.

SAMPLE DATA

I have a Table called RTLBarCode
It has a field called Barcode and a field called StockItemCode

For StockItemCode = 10 I have 2 rows with a Barcode value of 5014721112824 and 0000000019149.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Many thanks

Comment: Some sample data would be nice.

Comment: To Be honest since you are only unpivoting one column you probably don't need to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are indexing your barcode in unpiv.
This results in `col`'s-values `barcode1` and `barcode2`.

But then you are pivoting on `barcode` instead of `barcode1`. No value is found and the aggregate returns `null`.

The correct statement would be:

```
select StockItemCode, barcode1, barcode2 from 
(
    select StockItemCode, col+cast(seq as varchar(20)) col, value   
    from  
    (
        select 
                (select min(StockItemCode)from RTLBarCode t2 where t.StockItemCode = t2.StockItemCode) StockItemCode,  
                cast(BarCode as varchar(20)) barcode, 
                row_number() over(partition by StockItemCode order by StockItemCode) seq
        from RTLBarCode t
     ) d  
     unpivot(value for col in (barcode)) unpiv
) src 
pivot (max(value) for col in (barcode1, barcode2)) piv
```